# Uniform convergence of $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{ln}(n)^{x}}{n}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Given that the series $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\dfrac{\mathrm{ln}(n)^{p}}{n}$$ is convergent iff $p<-1$, show that $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{ln}(n)^{x}}{n}$$ is uniformly convergent as $x \in ]-\infty,p]$ where $p<-1$.

(Presumably using Weierstrass M-Test, but I feel the argument is lacking).

Comment: Nothing is lacking. $(\ln n)^x\leq (\ln n)^p$ for every $x\leq p<-1$. And $\ln n\geq 1$. So you have normal convergence (or Weierstrass M-test applies, if you prefer), hence uniform convergence.

Comment: If I use Weierstrass M-test, would it look like (wait a momemnt - reediting)

Comment: Forget my ealier comment. I mistakely pressed "enter" and didn't know it's same as pressing "Add comment". What I would say; I agree that $\mathrm{ln}(n)^x\leq \mathrm{ln}(n)^p$ if $x\leq p<-1$. But why is $\mathrm{ln}(n)\geq 1$? I am sorry if I again show my stupidity, I still don't know how to show in correctly way that it converges if I use Weierstrass M-test.

Comment: You need $\ln n\geq 1$ for the inequality to hold. And you get that for $n\geq 3$. As $n\geq 3\geq e$ gives $\ln n\geq \ln e=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f_n(x)=\frac{(\ln(n))^x}{n}$. Then we have 
$$
\sup_{(a,b)}|f_n(x)|=\sup_{(-\infty,p]}|\frac{(\ln(n))^x}{n}|\leq |\frac{(\ln(n))^p}{n}|,~(x\leq p<-1) \\
\leq |(\ln(n))^p|=(\ln(n))^p.
$$
We have that 
$$
\sum^{\infty}_{n=2}(\ln(n))^p<\infty,~p<-1
$$
hence we have uniform convergence.